# Can the exit beacon be unreachable from all other beacons?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I just encountered a interesting RNG result. See the marked star? It cannot be jumped to, from anywhere. YES I have on-mouse-over-routes turned on. Could the game in theory, make such a star the exit point, therefore preventing someone from continuing.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried jumping to it from the lower of the two systems you can currently jump to?

Comment: That is quite unusual! Usually all nodes atleast have one path connecting to them. If not it might be a bug in the game that you might want to report to the developers in the Official Forums - http://www.ftlgame.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=9&sid=8e56a4b2ac397dab8d2c8c0176236a7c

Comment: Do you have max engine upgrades? That increases jump range, so if you don't it may be reachable, but just not with your current engines.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie the wiki does not mention under its Engines page, that upgrading them increases your jump range. Nor does it say this in-game. Can you source that?

Comment: Engines don't increase jump range, someone has been making stuff up about that on the wikis for a while now.

Comment: @Ender & Joe Aha! I think I know why! IIRC the in-game text says that engines increas "FTL Speed". I seem to have misinterpreted that to mean range, when it apparently means chargeup speed. I bet others have too.

Comment: @kalina I have on mouse show routes on, I can mouse over the systems you mentioned and see that they do not have routes to the mentioned star.

Comment: @Ender ah ok - I've never experienced an instance of a node being inaccessible before.

Comment: I had an unreachable node just yesterday.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the game is never unbeatable due to inaccessible exit beacons. There should also never be an inaccessible quest beacon. However inaccessible beacons do exist, and it's by design.

[From Matthew Davis, developer of FTL:](http://www.ftlgame.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1908&start=10)

> I miss when games weren't laundry lists to check off things to do as I worked my way through it without issue. In the "old days" it might have been due to bugs, design, or just my flawed memory, but I preferred worlds where sometimes quests wouldn't be solve-able and not every location was reachable. It made the world feel whole and complete. Like there was more going on than the player was privy to... I don't see it as a problem. FTL has had this for 12 months, it's been left for a reason :-/
>
> On the other hand, quests were never intended to spawn at unreachable locations and that should have been fixed as of the last patch. And **the exit should always be reachable** (which was the original purpose of this thread). So if those bugs show up please show me screenshots / send me saves.